# east way to get all combinations in R from a list

Tags: r, list, combinations

I have the list below.

Suppose, i want 1 element from group1, 2 from group2, 3 from group3, 1 from groups 4 - 6. What's the most R like way to get all the different element combinations if elements are not allowed to repeat.

So for instance:
`(A1, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, D1, E1, F1)` is ok but `(A1, B1, B1, C1, C2, C3, D1, E1, F1)` is not?

```
itemNames <- list(group1 = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"),
                  group2 = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"),
                  group3 = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", "C12"),
                  group4 = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6"),
                  group5 = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"),
                  group6 = c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"))
```

Oviously, I can do this with 9 nested for loops -- a waste. I was playing with melt and reshape2 but haven't gotten anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for any item to be a part of more than one group?

Comment: @blakeoft -- no. Even if the "value" was, that should still count as a separate entity.

Comment: Ok. What about group6? I'm assuming that it should just have one draw as well.

Comment: @blakeoft -- yep. Sorry, I've edited the post.

Comment: Title says "all combinations", which would be _a lot_. Did you mean perhaps a random sample thereof?

Comment: No -- I mean in fact all. Ignoring replicates -- I count there's about 35 million. That should be fine for R.

Comment: I think I may have spotted an error. Should group3 contain "C4" as an item?

Comment: @blakeoft: yes, it should. Fixed.

Comment: @blakeoft That count contains "A1 B1 B2..." and "A1 B2 B1..." as two distinct options. If you strictly want combinations of the subgroups, not permutations, divide that count by arrangements in the subgroups `22809600/factorial(3)/factorial(2) = 1900800`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Map` `Reduce` functional combination. Map `combn` to obtain the combinations of each group. Then reduce with a version of `expand.grid` that does not flatten.

```
expand.grid.XY <- function(X,Y) 
  cbind(X[rep(1:nrow(X),nrow(Y)),], Y[rep(1:nrow(Y),each=nrow(X)),])

combos <- function(items,reps)
  Reduce(expand.grid.XY, Map(function(...) t(combn(...)),items,reps))

dim(combos(itemNames,c(1,2,3,1,1,1)))
# [1] 1900800       9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
itemNames <- list(group1 = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"),
                  group2 = c("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"),
                  group3 = c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10","C11","C12"),
                  group4 = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6"),
                  group5 = c("E1","E2","E3","E4"),
                  group6 = c("F1","F2","F3","F4"))


f <- function(x, n) {
  tmp <- t(combn(length(x),n))
  p <- function(...) paste(..., sep = ',')
  do.call('p', lapply(1:n, function(xx) as.matrix(x)[tmp[, xx]]))
}

tmp <- Map(f, itemNames, c(1,2,3,1,1,1))

Reduce(`*`, Map(choose, sapply(tmp, length), 1))
# [1] 1900800

dim(out <- expand.grid(tmp))
# [1] 1900800       6
format(object.size(out), units = 'Mb')
# [1] "43.5 Mb"

head(out)
#   group1 group2 group3 group4 group5 group6
# 1     A1   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1
# 2     A2   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1
# 3     A3   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1
# 4     A4   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1
# 5     A5   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1
# 6     A6   B1B2 C1C2C3     D1     E1     F1

out <- apply(out, 1, paste0, collapse = ',')

(out <- strsplit(out, ','))[1:5]
# [[1]]
# [1] "A1" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "E1" "F1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "A2" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "E1" "F1"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "A3" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "E1" "F1"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "A4" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "E1" "F1"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "A5" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "E1" "F1"
```

No duplicates:

```
any(duplicated(out))
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another iteration

```
ex <- c(1,2,3,1,1,1)

lst <- lapply(seq(itemNames), function(i) 
                             combn(itemNames[[i]], ex[i], toString))

out <- do.call("expand.grid", lst)

head(out)
#  Var1   Var2       Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
#1   A1 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1
#2   A2 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1
#3   A3 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1
#4   A4 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1
#5   A5 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1
#6   A6 B1, B2 C1, C2, C3   D1   E1   F1

dim(out)
#[1] 1900800       6

prod(sapply(lst, length))
#[1] 1900800
```